# How to get the current word starting from the cursor?

Tags: vimscript

In vimscript `expand('<cword>')` gives me the word under the cursor.

How can I get the word under the cursor starting at he current cursor location (skipping the word start).

Comment: Can I ask why? `ye` should do it, but moves the cursor.

Comment: I want to use the result of `ye` for fzf find, but without changing the cursor or my cut buffer.

Comment: Use a different buffer? `"aye`

Comment: But how to extract this in vimscript?

Comment: Is there something open in your question? How can we help you further? Otherwise may be could accept a solution. It allows the question to rest :-)

Answer (score 1):

Using vimscript: `matchstr(getline('.'), '\k*', getpos('.')[2]-1)`.

`getline('.')` gets the current line, `matchstrpos` searches for the current keyword pattern `\k*` starting from the current cursor position from `getpos('.')`, where current cursor position is at the second index and we need to subtract 1 to index the search correctly.